# I want to disable drop if condition is not met in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

This is my controller code:

```
$scope.drop=  function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
$scope.openDialog = function($event) {
        if(true){
//allow drop
}
            if(false){
                //disable drop
                }

             }
```

This is my html code for drag and drop method calling:

Here I have created a table and it that table TD I want to drop something if condition met.

```
<td ng-repeat="col in input_columns" ondrop="angular.element(document.getElementById('table')).scope().drop(event)" ondragover="angular.element(document.getElementById('table')).scope().allowDrop(event)" ng-click="openDialog($event)" tempValue="">&lt;enter data&gt;</td>
```

Now how can i disable drop through angular, if the condition is not met

Comment: Why invent the wheel? There are plenty of "angular drop"-libraries out there, such as: https://github.com/caitp/angular-drop

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
ondrop="{{colDropEvent()}}"
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.colDropEvent = function() {
    if (your_condition) {
        angular.element(document.getElementById('table')).scope().drop(event);
    }
}
```

You can also put a ng-class and try in css: `pointer-events: none`

Comment: While using your approach I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: colDropEvent is not definedondrop

Comment: Is there any property in $event which can disable the drop and give the black circle with a slash representing here we cannot drop

Comment: You have to implement it urself using css.  Tried the other option I suggested?

Comment: No, I didn't tried CSS solution..I am trying it too